# How to check if an object at on a specific position/how to get the position of an object

Tags: game-engine

I'm working on a project and I need to get the position of an object (not necessarily by python code) and at the same time I need to know how I can check if the position is on a special point like (0,3,6) for example. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found out now, if someone needs to know, this is how I get the positions:

import bge
import GameLogic as g

cont = g.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
pos = own.position
x = pos[0]
y = pos[1]
z = pos[2]

and this is how I check for them:
if x = 3.0 and 2.5 and y == 3 and z == 2.5:
    print("The object has the coordinates (3.0|2.5|2.5)")

Comment: Equal checks are no good idea. Due to imprecision of the number representations the object might be very close. Better calculate the distance to the reference position and check if the distance is inside a certain range.